# Which type of integrals are better for Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Is it in general better to type in a integral *with* its limits, or is it better to type an indefinite integral into Mathematica? With better I mean: Likelihood that Mathematica can solve it, computation time and so on.

For instance suppose you have a quite complicated integral $$I=\int_\ell^u dx \, f(a,b,c,d;x) $$ where $a,b,c,d$ are all parameters you know the value of, but perhaps you would like to keep the parameters as they are and not plug in the numbers. What would then be a good strategy to evaluate $I$? Plug in all the numbers $(a,b,c,d,\ell,u)$ or not? Or perhaps it does not matter so much for Mathematica?

Comment: Depends on the integral. Sometimes one is easier to do than the other.

Comment: Plugging in all the numbers is almost always easier. Integrals with symbolic parameters have to generate conditions on those parameters, do all kinds of checking etc... Symbolic integrals are more generalized - you'd naturally expect these more general integrals to be harder to reason about because their antiderivatives describe a much wider class of functions. Some definite integrals (limits) are really slow however usually because of discontinuities or removable singularities in the path of integration.

Comment: Yes of course I suspected that with general parameter the integrals should be more complicated, but on the other hand I want to know whether this really is true for Mathematica. Suppose one has very complicated mix of large and small numericals (numbers) inside the integrand, then perhaps for some cases it is better to keep the parameters and then plug in numbers after integration, but I don't know.